# What do I set ProductID to in HOST-RESOURCES-MIB

Tags: snmp, mib, opennms

I'm implementing an SNMP agent in python and am using the MIB `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB`. One of the fields that I need to set is `hrSWRunID`. This OID is defined to be of type `ProductID` and the definition for `ProductID` states

> ProductID ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
>       STATUS current
>       DESCRIPTION
>           "This textual convention is intended to identify the
>
> ```
>     manufacturer, model, and version of a specific
>     hardware or software product.  It is suggested that
>     these OBJECT IDENTIFIERs are allocated such that all
>     products from a particular manufacturer are registered
>     under a subtree distinct to that manufacturer.  In
>     addition, all versions of a product should be
>     registered under a subtree distinct to that product.
>     With this strategy, a management station may uniquely
>     determine the manufacturer and/or model of a product
>     whose productID is unknown to the management station.
>     Objects of this type may be useful for inventory
>     purposes or for automatically detecting
>     incompatibilities or version mismatches between
>     various hardware and software components on a system.
>
>     For example, the product ID for the ACME 4860 66MHz
>     clock doubled processor might be:
>     enterprises.acme.acmeProcessors.a4860DX2.MHz66
>
>     A software product might be registered as:
>     enterprises.acme.acmeOperatingSystems.acmeDOS.six(6).one(1)
>     "
> SYNTAX OBJECT IDENTIFIER
> ```
>
> -- unknownProduct will be used for any unknown ProductID
>   -- unknownProduct OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { 0 0 }

From this I assumed that a value of `com.mycompany.mydepartment.myapp.appversion` would suffice but when I run the code it fails with an error `ProductID: invalid literal for int() with base 0: 'com'\n"]`

With a bit of experimentation I finally managed to run my code with a ProductID set to a set of numbers such as `{1, 2, 3}`.Although my code now works I'm no clearer on what a correct value should be.

Can anyone shed any light on what ProductID is or should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ProductID would be the OBJECT IDENTIFIER of a MIB object defined
under your enterprise MIB. A good start would be to make it the same as
the sysObjectID of your system group.

Comment: OK. That would make sense. In may case I'm writing code for a python application that I want to monitor using OpenNMS and as such I don't have an enterprise MIB.

Comment: In that case use unknownProduct, or use any other OID. The management app wants to resolve the name, and may enable certain functionality for known ProductIDs.